# notation - What does max over a summation of single term mean?

Tags: summation, notation

Given the following `max` expression, what does it mean?

$\max_{j=1\ldots n} \left(\sum_{k=1}^{j} A_{\pi(k)} + \sum_{k=j}^{n} B_{\pi(k)}\right).$

Here

$\sum_{k=1}^{j} A_{\pi(k)}$

and

$\sum_{k=j}^{n} B_{\pi(k)}$

are both integers.

What is the meaning of `max(A+B)`? **Why would you do a max over a single term?**

A `max` of multiple terms makes sense but why do it over a single term?

Comment: The term $\sum_{k=1}^{j} A_{\pi(k)} + \sum_{k=j}^{n} B_{\pi(k)}$ dépends on $j$ ! It is the same as writing $\max \left(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\right)$ with $a_j=\sum_{k=1}^{j} A_{\pi(k)} + \sum_{k=j}^{n} B_{\pi(k)}$.

Comment: You take the maximum over the range $j = 1,\dots,n$.

Comment: Why are notation questions always down voted? Is there a math notation to english converter present which I can use?